# Message versioning in RabbitMQ / AMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

What is the recommended way to deal with message versioning? The main schools of thought appear to be:

1. Always create a new message class as the message structure changes
2. Never use (pure) serialized objects as a message. Always use some kind of version header field and a byte stream body field. In this way, the receiver can always accept the message and check the version number before attempting to read the message body.
3. Never use binary serialized objects as a message. Instead, use a textual form such as JSON. In this way, the receiver can always accept the message, check the version number, and then (when possible) understand the message body.

As I want to keep my messages compact I am considering using [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) which would allow me to satisfy both 2 & 3.

However I am interested in real world experiences and advice on how to handle versioning of messages as their structure changes?

Comment: IMHO protobuf is a good choice. Your question seems best answered via search engines ... for instance, this appears to address protobuf pretty well -https://www.beautifulcode.co/backward-and-forward-compatibility-protobuf-versioning-serialization

Comment: @Luke In conjunction with a version header as described in 2.?

Answer (score 0):

In this case "version" will be basically some metadata about the message, And these metadata are some instruction/hints to the processing algorithm. So I willsuggest to add such metadata in the header (outside of the payload), so that consumer can read the metadata first before trying to read/understand and process the message payload. For example,  if you keep the version info in the payload and due to some reason your (message payload is corrupted) then algorithm will fail parse the message, then it can not event reach the metadata you have put there.

You may consider to have both version and type info of the payload in one header.